# value from a range in .interior.color \ VBA EXCEL 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I have in column F numbers , each number refers to a color code, I'm trying to auto change each cell color in F based on its value , BUT ALL COMES ONLY IN BLACK , below is my code :

Sub Highlight()

```
 For Each C In Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("F3:F1000")


With Sheet3.Range("$F1:$F1000")
    .FormatConditions.Delete

    With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=($F1<>"""")")
        .Interior.Color = C.Value
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
 End With

 End With
 Next C
```

End Sub

Help please & thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=($F1<>"""")") meant to have a bracket in it? Should it be Add.Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=($F1<>"""")"  ?

Comment: thank you first , that is giving me error , actually I don't know but the one in my code is doing its part correctly : I tried to test color vbRed the code works very well ,but of course all cells are in Red , while I want to read each cell value and give color accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split your code to 2 `Sub`s:

1. `Sub CondFormat` - to apply conditional formatting (once).
2. `Sub Highlight` - to apply cell color based on it's value - more frequently.

---

### Code

```
Option Explicit

Dim LastRow As Long

Sub CondFormat()

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("F1:F" & LastRow)
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=($F1<>" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
    End With

End With

End Sub


Sub Highlight()

Dim Rng As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each Rng In .Range("F3:F" & LastRow)
        Rng.Interior.Color = Rng.Value
        Rng.Font.Color = vbWhite
    Next Rng
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Mr. Rado , thanks for the effort , but it gives error : subscript out of range, just to mention that my color values are all above 58.

Comment: @YAMEN-K at what line are you getting an error ? my values are all above 58, actualy it's all the way up to 3,000,000 and it's working fine. Since you are using the `RGB` method, it's supports all the way to 256^3.

Comment: something is wrong , with worksheets() is showing the error ,although I changed to my sheet ref number with worksheets("sheet8")

Comment: @YAMEN-K is your worksheet named "Sheet8" ? or it's the index of the worksheet ?

Comment: index , you mean I should change it to the name ?

Comment: my bad , you are amazing ,it works PERFECTLY , thank you so much SIR.

Comment: @YAMEN-K yes, when you use `With Worksheets("Sheet3")` , the name of the worksheet is "Sheet" , not the third on the workbook order

Answer (score 0):

As you've already got a loop to repeat over the cells in F3:F1000, it would be enough to use that. The main thing is changing .Interior.Color to .Interior.ColorIndex

```
Sub Highlight()

For Each C In Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("F3:F1000")

If (C <> "") Then
    C.Interior.ColorIndex = C.Value
    C.Font.Color = vbWhite
End If

Next C
End Sub
```

The only issue is that if any of the numbers in your cells were greater than 56, you would get a subscript error in the ColorIndex values. You could make it recycle the colours by putting

```
c.Interior.ColorIndex = (c.Value - 1) Mod 56 + 1
```

Comment: thank you Tom , as you've predicted I am using custom colors and all codes are > 58 ,which shows a subscript error , do you suggest a solution in such a case ? thanks in advance

Comment: my concern that if I change the code to : .Interior.Color = vbRed ( for example ) or any number ( 111 ) it works perfectly ,but all will be in one color as you see , so for some reason =C.value is giving me black for all

Comment: I tried too to make the range one cell , the cell color is turning white !

Comment: If you're using Interior.Color rather than Interior.ColorIndex, you need to set it to a colour using RGB(r,g,b) where r,g and b are integers 0-255. So you'd need a way to map the numbers in column F to those three integers. What is the range of your numbers in column F?

Comment: no, in column f I have colors like this example ( 16775408 ) this is Alice Blue I got a whole set of such colors from the net .

Comment: I have just tried setting the range to your number using c.Interior.Color = 16775408 and it does give pale blue. It also works if you put that number into one of the cells and use c.Interior.Color = c.Value